# How can I graphically render audio(visualizations)?

Tags: windows, macos, audio, visualization

I want to create very high resolution graphic representations of some high bitrate WAV files I have for printing in a book a la art project. Here's some examples:

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

I could just get a trial / buy Audition or Soundbooth but those will just be screen resolution. Is there any software that will render at a higher res but in an artistic style?

Comment: When I specified very high resolution, I was hoping for something that would render in the 6mp range.  That said, it seems like setting my desktop resolution to the highest possible setting (I think I have a 36" monitor out there somewhere) and doing a screenshot of one of the itunes visualizers might do the trick.  I would still like to know if there are any other options before accepting, however.

Comment: One more point I'd like to make and this is more important than I first realized - while the itunes visualizers will give me a snapshot of that MOMENT in the audio, I would like something that shows the WHOLE of the audio file as shown in my examples.

Comment: Ah, if you want the whole file then Breakaway RTS is not the right tool then!

Answer (score 1):

[Breakaway RTA](http://www.claessonedwards.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=554&start=0) is free and can display either oscilloscopes, meters or both

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [iTunes](http://www.apple.com/itunes/) visualizers.

For example:

- [WhiteCap](http://www.soundspectrum.com/whitecap/) (seems to meet your requirements?)
- [GasLight](http://www.steelskies.com/gaslight/)

But others should exist !

> **WhiteCap**:
>
> [image: whitecap]
>
> **GasLight**:
>
> [image: gaslight]

Answer (score 1):

**[Plasmavis](http://www.plasmavis.com/plasmavis.html)** creates countless varieties of high resolution animations from the music playing in Windows Media Player, responding directly to rhythm, volume, and pitch changes.High Performance, hardware-accelerated graphics produce elaborate displays by varying and combining hundreds of mathematical formulas for movement, a multitude of color patterns, and textures. The ever changing display is, twisting, exploding, kaleidoscopic, fractal-like, galactic, flowing, geometrical, radiant, and most often simply "indescribable".

[image]

*Plasmavis is freeware, the $9 shareware version offers even more features.*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to visualise the whole file then [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/about/features) has some functionality that may be of use:

> Analysis

```
* Spectrogram mode for visualizing frequencies.
* “Plot Spectrum” command for detailed frequency analysis
```

Audacity also supports [LADSPA](http://www.ladspa.org/) plugins so you may find something else of use there...