# LIVE Visual feedback for audio output on OSX

Tags: macos, audio, html

I am coding with basic HTML5 web audio.   I sometimes however, have to code in class, or a place where sound can't be played.

Is there an application that shows the output signal of the speakers on the OS level (OSX) ? (similar to the input signal meter of the mic in System Preferences).

Please keep in mind that the audio signal is coming LIVE from the browser ( I use chrome preferably, and ff on occasion ).

Part of the challenge here is that I am mapping animations to the sound, and am trying to match them in time, and if I see when there is sound, I can know if the animation is timed correctly.  I am also trying to have visual feedback REGARDLESS of where the audio signal is coming from, simply put, I want to gain access to the voltage being supplied to the speakers, although in this case if there is an addon to Chrome or FF I will be happy with application specific solutions.

The similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/110682/how-can-i-graphically-render-audiovisualizations) only addresses audio files, not live audio from another application.

Comment: Why did you delete your question and re-post it? If it's not a duplicate, we could have just reopened it… Deleting closed questions and re-posting isn't encouraged, so please don't do it.

Comment: I edited the posting, and appealed. I waited a day, and then did it.   StackExchange also doesn't easily provide for challenges, so like in this case, this question actually affects more than myself, it affects  our lab group .  I just have the account. And even if they were to join, they don't have enough reputation to challenge 5 moderators, especially since they are actually different questions, but easily misinterpreted as the same.  Much like the US law makers, you can appeal more than once for a law, even after others reject.   This question attempts to make the distinction even clearer.

Comment: If a question is edited after being closed, it is put into a review queue where it can be reopened from. You didn't edit your question, but deleted it. On [help/duplicates](http://superuser.com/help/duplicates) and [help/reopen-questions](http://superuser.com/help/reopen-questions) there are plenty ways mentioned on how to reopen a question. In any case, please remember that for the next time. There isn't much to worry about for now.

Comment: Well, we here at research I schools are somewhat overloaded, much like the rest of the US (Internship in France was awesome, 35 hours a week, and they go home, no working from home).  But given certain class requirements and the content of that particular day, it is not always efficient to devote 100% attention to the instruction.  ie, I stidy HCI, the talk is on energy efficiency in a sub routine bubble sorts using GPUs, but yes, I understand the concern.